# How to update table using "beans"

Tags: redbean

How do I  convert this query to redbeans?

```
update trips set title="test" where title="Rome 9 days"
```

I know I cand do R:: exec () but I am wondering if it's the only way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$bean = R::findOne('trips', 'title = ?', array('Rome 9 days'));
$bean->title = "test";
R::store($bean);
```

This should work